# Onclick function on td element Kendo Scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a table that is generated by a Kendo Scheduler.
I have to add a click function on each td on document load.

For now, I have tried this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.k-nonwork-hour').click(function () {

        alert("Hello");

        });
   });
```

For adding a onclick function. I have also tried with onclick

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.k-nonwork-hour').onclick =function () {

        alert("Hello");

       };
    });
```

But none of them works. Anyone knows a solution? :)

Comment: mh are there maybe errors in the javascript console? maybe the td.k-nonwork... selector is wrong cause this http://jsfiddle.net/52fkT/ is working

Comment: Please show HTML after kendo.

Comment: I do not think there is errors in the javascript console. It must be something with the td.k-nonwork class, because I can get it to work with other types of classes. Actually it is the whole table, which I cannot get a respond on with the onclick. I have also tried to specify the table name, like `$('.randomTableName .k-nonwork-hour').onclick =function ()...` , but with no help.

Answer (score 3):

Better use delegated event instead of attaching event handler to each cell.

e.g.

```
       scheduler.wrapper.on("click", "td.k-nonwork-hour", function() {
        alert("Non working day!")
       });
```

[Here](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/aJaL) is live example.

Answer (score 0):

```
scheduler.wrapper.on("mouseup touchend", ".k-scheduler-table td, .k-event", function(e) {
        var target = $(e.currentTarget);

        if (target.hasClass("k-event")) {
            var event = scheduler.occurrenceByUid(target.data("uid"));
            scheduler.editEvent(event);
        } else {
            var slot = scheduler.slotByElement(target[0]);

            scheduler.addEvent({
                start: slot.startDate,
                end: slot.endDate
            });
        }
    });
```